Identifying corresponding credits and invoices in a database using SQL
I am new to SQL and I have a database that has a list of invoices and their details.



Date
TransNo
accountcode
transdate
transtype
invoreceiptno
NLCode
invalue




2019-01-20
252814
J0125
2019-02-04
I
58832
Visitors
450.02


2019-01-20
253023
P1485
2019-02-13
I
58926
Visitors
413.1


2019-01-20
253050
L0853
2019-02-15
I
58938
Visitors
242.15


2019-01-20
253051
L0853
2019-02-15
C
1831
Visitors
-242.15


2019-01-20
253052
L0853
2019-02-15
I
58939
Visitors
297.85



I am trying to create a list of only the invoices that have been credited with the corresponding credit line so that I can view them and then drop them from the database that I am working with
So from the above the result would be:



Date
TransNo
accountcode
transdate
transtype
invoreceiptno
NLCode
invalue




2019-01-20
253050
L0853
2019-02-15
I
58938
Visitors
242.15


2019-01-20
253051
L0853
2019-02-15
C
1831
Visitors
-242.15



Some invoices were credited and the credits appear as a separate line in the database, however they don't have the same invoice number as the original invoice. The only way to identify those invoices that have been credited is to find two lines with the same accountcode, that have the same transaction amount (negative for the credit). (as in the example above, the invoice and credit for 242.15)
I tried to find these lines like this:
select *
from tablename AS inv
  INNER JOIN tablename AS cr 
    ON  inv.accountcode = cr.accountcode
    AND inv.invalue = -cr.invalue
WHERE inv.invalue > 0
ORDER BY inv.Date

There are two problems with the result using this - 1. There are multiple invoices with the same amount and it gives me all of them. and 2. It doesn't give me the credit line (but if I exclude the WHERE line it processed for ages and didn't give me a result)
Any suggestions of how I can just find (and then drop) the specific invoices that were credited?

Sample data is great, but you also need to specify the expected result, i.e. provide a complete [mcve].

There can be invoices with and without credits. So, you must outer join the credits to the invoices. Then you need a precise role which invoice to attach a credit to. If for instance you have five rows with the same account and amounts (ordered by date old to new): I, I, C, I, C: Which I shall the first C refer to, which I the second?

What is your DBMS? Always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS. The solution may require window functions, lateral joins or a recursive query, which some DBMS feature and some not, and some differ in syntax.

@ThorstenKettner if I understood your question correctly, I am using Microsoft SSMS (is that what you meant by DBMS? Sorry, I am very much a beginner)

@jarlh I added expected results, I hope this is what was meant

SSMS is a GUI tool to work with the databases in a database management system (DBMS). From what I read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16, the only supported DBMS are SQL Server and Azure, so it is very likely that you are using Microsoft SQL Server. I've tagged your request accordingly.

There can be multiple invoices with the same amount for an account. Accordingly there can be multiple credits with that same amount.
Example:



Date
TransNo
accountcode
transdate
transtype
invoreceiptno
NLCode
invalue




2019-01-20
253050
L0853
2019-02-15
I
58938
Visitors
100.00


2019-01-20
253051
L0853
2019-02-15
I
58940
Visitors
100.00


2019-01-20
253052
L0853
2019-02-15
C
1831
Visitors
-100.00


2019-01-20
253053
L0853
2019-02-15
I
58941
Visitors
100.00


2019-01-20
253054
L0853
2019-02-15
C
1833
Visitors
-100.00



Assuming that the fist credit belongs to the first invoice and the second credit belongs to the second invoice, all you have to do is number your invoices and credits per account and value ordered by time and consider these numbers in the join.
WITH
  inv AS
  (
    SELECT 
      mytable.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY accountcode, invalue ORDER BY date, transdate, transno) AS rn
    FROM mytable
    WHERE transtype = 'I' AND invalue > 0
  ),
  crd as
  (
    SELECT
      mytable.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY accountcode, invalue ORDER BY date, transdate, transno) AS rn
    FROM mytable
    WHERE transtype = 'C' AND invalue < 0
  )
SELECT *
FROM inv
LEFT OUTER JOIN crd
    ON  crd.accountcode = inv.accountcode
    AND crd.invalue     = -inv.invalue
    AND crd.rn          = inv.rn
ORDER BY inv.date, inv.transdate, inv.transno;

I am not sure which columns to use for ordering the rows. Maybe you'll have do adjust the ORDER BY clauses.

Thanks very much! RIGHT OUTER JOIN worked better for me so that I could see all the credits rather than all the invoices. If I then want to delete these rows, would adding in:
DELETE FROM table name
WHERE rn in (
above the SELECT work?

I didn't expect there could be credits without invoices. Right outer joins should be avoided for their lack of readability. Better just switch the tables and stay with a left join: FROM crd LEFT OUTER JOIN inv ON .... If you want to use this for a delete, then you should not use an outer join at all, because then you'd delete all rows whether they have a match or not. As to the delete syntax: I don't know. I don't use SQL Server, so I don't know which syntax is most appropriate. In Oracle, PostgreSQL or SQLite I would work with the row address (ROWID/CTID). In SQL Server I don't know.
